# Type of X is incompatible with type of XXXX

Tags: vhdl, error

I have the following code(I'm pretty new in VHDL):

```
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_unsigned.ALL;

entity prac6 is
    Port ( P1 : in  STD_LOGIC;
           P0 : in  STD_LOGIC;
           D3 : in  STD_LOGIC;
           D2 : in  STD_LOGIC;
           D1 : in  STD_LOGIC;
           D0 : in  STD_LOGIC;
           F : out  STD_LOGIC;
           J1 : out  STD_LOGIC;
           J2 : out  STD_LOGIC);
end prac6;

architecture DM of prac6 is --0
    
    signal product: std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    signal cash_v: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    signal cash_int: integer range 0 to 15;
    signal price: integer range 0 to 7;
    signal change: integer range 0 to 15;
begin
    
    product <= P1&P0;
    cash_v <= D3&D2&D1&D0;
    cash_int <= conv_integer(cash_v);
    price <= 2 when product = "00" else    -- Coca Cola 2€
                 3 when product = "01" else     -- Patatas fritas 3€
                 5 when product = "10" else     -- Postre dulce 5€
                 6 when product = "11";         -- Albóndigas 6€
                 
process (change, cash_int, price)--1
begin

    if (cash_int - price) >= 0 then
        change <= cash_int - price;
        F <= '0';
    else
        change <= price - cash_int;
        F <= '1';
end if;

case change is --2
    when 0 => J2 <= "0011"; J1 <= "1111";
    when 1 => J2 <= "0000"; J1 <= "0110";
    when 2 => J2 <= "0101"; J1 <= "1011";
    when 3 => J2 <= "0100"; J1 <= "1111";
    when 4 => J2 <= "0110"; J1 <= "0110";
    when 5 => J2 <= "0110"; J1 <= "1101";
    when 6 => J2 <= "0111"; J1 <= "1101";
    when 7 => J2 <= "0000"; J1 <= "0111";
    when 8 => J2 <= "0111"; J1 <= "1111";
    when 9 => J2 <= "0110"; J1 <= "1111";
    when others => J2 <= "0000"; J1 <= "0000";

end case;--2

end process;--1

end DM; --0
```

The errors I have are these(I don't know how to fix them) :
[image]

Comment: `J1` and `J2` are `STD_LOGIC` typed but you're trying to assign them vectors. Did you mean to use `STD_LOGIC_VECTOR`?

Comment: You shouldn't use `STD_LOGIC_unsigned`, use `numeric_std` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning `J1`, `J2` with `"0000"`, `"0011"` etc, which are inferred as `std_logic_vector` at RHS. But `J1` and `J2` at LHS are of `std_logic`. Re-analyze your requirements and fix data types of your IO ports to `std_logic_vector`, if that is what you really want.